# Multiple joins with SQLiteQueryBuilder

Tags: android, sqlite, query-builder

I am using content provider to store data in sqlite and using cursor adaptor to show data in my listview. 
I have 3 tables

1) Leads-[ _id,name,....]

2) LeadsAttachment-[ _id,format,LeadId,....] (LeadId is FK to _id PK of Leads table)

3) LeadsProduct-[ _id,pname,LeadId,....] (LeadId is FK to _id PK of Leads table)

uptill now i was performing left join between Leads and LeadsAttachment using SQLQueryBuilder like this

```
SQLiteQueryBuilder leadsWithAttachmentQueryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
leadsWithAttachmentQueryBuilder.setTables(
            MBenzContracts.LeadsEntry.TABLE_NAME + " LEFT JOIN " +
                    MBenzContracts.LeadAttachmentEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                    " ON " + MBenzContracts.LeadAttachmentEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                    "." + MBenzContracts.LeadAttachmentEntry.COLUMN_Lead_ID +
                    " = " + MBenzContracts.LeadsEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                    "." + MBenzContracts.LeadsEntry._ID);
```

How will i perform 2 left joins together in SQLiteQueryBuilder so that i get 
all the records from Leads along with LeadsAttachment and LeadsProduct

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, its very simple

```
leadsWithProductAndAttachmentQueryBuilder.setTables(
            MBenzContracts.LeadsEntry.TABLE_NAME + " LEFT JOIN " +
                    MBenzContracts.LeadProductEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                    " ON " + MBenzContracts.LeadProductEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                    "." + MBenzContracts.LeadProductEntry.COLUMN_Lead_ID +
                    " = " + MBenzContracts.LeadsEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                    "." + MBenzContracts.LeadsEntry._ID + " LEFT JOIN " +
                    MBenzContracts.LeadAttachmentEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                    " ON " + MBenzContracts.LeadAttachmentEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                    "." + MBenzContracts.LeadAttachmentEntry.COLUMN_Lead_ID +
                    " = " + MBenzContracts.LeadsEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                    "." + MBenzContracts.LeadsEntry._ID);
```